# Adding an eventListener to a dynamically created Select box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I'm trying to code a dynamically created select box within a dynamically created div that are both created on load of the page. My attempts to add an onchange Event Listener to the select box only trigger when the page is loaded, how do I go about fixing this? I'm new to both html and JavaScript so my code is intentionally basic. Here is my code:

```js
function createDiv()
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'main-div';
    div.id = 'mainDiv';
    div.setAttribute('title', 'Main Div');
    var divText = document.createTextNode("Select a Number ");
    div.appendChild(divText);

    var select = document.createElement('select')

    select.options[0] = new Option("1");
    select.options[1] = new Option("2");
    select.options[2] = new Option("3");
    select.options[3] = new Option("4");
    select.options[4] = new Option("5");
    select.options[5] = new Option("6");
    select.options[6] = new Option("7");
    select.options[7] = new Option("8");
    select.options[8] = new Option("9");
    select.options[9] = new Option("10");

    //select.addEventListener("change", alert("changed!"));

    div.appendChild(select);


    document.body.appendChild(div);
    console.log(div);
}
```

```html
<body onload = createDiv()>
    <h1 id = "heading1">Test</h1>
    <br>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `select.addEventListener` - that would be the way to do it

Comment: your issue is that you are adding the **result of calling alert** as the event handler ... you need to add a **function** as the event handler ... `select.addEventListener("change", () => alert("changed!"));`

Answer (score 1):

The method `addEventListener` need a function in second parameter, and you didn't pass a function but the result of the `alert()` function (that is void).

Change: `alert("changed!")` to

`function() {alert("changed!")}`

*(that can be shortened by `() => alert("changed!")` since [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies))*:

```js
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'main-div';
  div.id = 'mainDiv';
  div.setAttribute('title', 'Main Div');
  var divText = document.createTextNode("Select a Number ");
  div.appendChild(divText);
  
  var select = document.createElement('select')
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
    select.options[i] = new Option(i);
  }
  
  select.addEventListener("change", function() {alert("changed to "+select.value)});
  div.appendChild(select);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<body onload = createDiv()>
  <h1 id = "heading1">Test</h1>
</body>
```